# Cassandra. Default column value

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlengine

Following example from [python cassandra driver](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/object_mapper.html#getting-started)

```
class Users(Model):
    username = columns.Text(index=True, required=True)
    user_id = columns.UUID(index=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    email = columns.Text(primary_key=True, required=True)
    passwd = columns.Text()
    salt = columns.Text()
```

And creating object in following way:

```
u = Users()
u.username = 'admin'
u.email = 'test@test.com'
u.password = u'test'   #This is property with setter
Users.create(**dict(u))
```

In this case, we get `user_id:None` instead of `user_id:uuid.uuid4` and corresponding error.

How to make `default = uuid.uuid4` work with less pain?

**UPD** I guess, it's caused by overriding [`to_database`](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/cqlengine/columns.py#L522) method in UUID column. Which conflicts with base [`to_database`](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/cqlengine/columns.py#L187) method.

**UPD2** Looks like bad case. Error happens on step `**dict(u)`

**Solution:**

```
d = dict(u) 
del d['column_with_default_value']
Users.create(**d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a lot more work than you need to.  Given your table, this is how you insert:

`Users.create(username="admin", email="test@test.com", passwd="test")`

I've verified this here:

`In [16]: Users.create(username="admin", email="test@test.com", passwd="test")
Out[16]: Users(username='admin', user_id=UUID('183d542d-c469-448d-9d14-d3614f727cef'), email='test@test.com', passwd='test', salt=None)`

Comment: How you will trigger property in `create` method? I use password property, that sets passwd field and salt.

Comment: And yes, I don't want to take care of manually creating UUID's :)

Comment: If you will pass property to `create` - you will get error `ValidationError: Incorrect columns passed: set(['password'])` in current case.

Comment: I can't see the rest of your code I have no idea what you're doing, sorry.